# How to Debug an Apache Crash?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I have a website which has a traffic of ~100k visitors a day. We are running on WordPress, and have 3 app servers with RackSpace. There are days when the servers can support ~1200 live visitors without slowing down, and on some days, the RAM usage peaks with just ~500 users and the servers crash. I have basic knowledge of system admin. How do I find out what is consuming all the RAM? I think it's a WordPress issue, rather than an Apache issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at /var/log/apache2/error.log you will see if apache is working right, or crashing.

Comment: This gives me all the php errors. I am using W3TC plugin, so most of the errors I get are - apc_store() unable to allocate memory to pool

My system admin guy tells me that PHP isn't able to free up memory. I am trying to understand how to track which process / function / file is taking up the memory. Also, the memory bottleneck is intermittent. It runs fine most of the time.

Would apache-status be able to help? Is it possible to log the apache-status file?

Comment: Take a look at this. Maybe helps: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. There is sufficient buffer during normal usage. And then the CPU and memory usage suddenly starts peaking. This happened for some 20 - 30 mins today, and I wasn't around, so I don't really know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

> How to debug an apache crash?

Did it crash? If so then you should have a core dump - generate a stack trace from it. (I suspect it dodn't really crash).

> has a traffic of ~100k visitors a day

Good metric for marketing - useless for systems admin.

> have 3 app servers with RackSpace....peaks with just ~500 users and the servers crash

All three servers "crash" simultaeneously? Highly improbable.

> apc_store() unable to allocate memory to pool

What is the memory usage on the OS? What is the [memory usage in APC](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apc-php-cache-information/)?